# How to map class attributes with seq of variables?

Tags: scala

I'm having one case class like below

```
case class VariablesToMap{

          id: int,    // for ex : 100
          name: String,  // for ex Jon
          country: String, // for ex USA
          pincode: String, // for ex 121212
          state: String, // for ex Texas
          ssn: String // for ex ABCGS125AJH
}
```

I've a instance of VariablesToMap class which is having values against its attributes (id, name and country and so on).

Now I've Seq of variables too, for examples `Seq[String] myColumns = Seq[String]("id", "name","country")`

That means I've all elements present `myColumns`  are available in VariablesToMap class's attributes, since all values of attributes are mentioned in VariablesToMap class's attributes, I want map all these values to all available elements in `myColumns`  and return a string like below

`op: String = /id=100/name=Jon/country=USA/`

Can I have suggestions to solve this ?

Thanks

Thinking of solving this, didnt get any possible solution

Comment: I would just use `map` + _pattern matching_, and then `mkString`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez any example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you are using scala 2.13, you can do something like this:

```
foo.productElementNames.zip(foo.productIterator)
   .collect { case x@(name, _) if myColumns.contains(name) => x }
   .map { case (name, value) => s"$name=$value" }
   .mkString("/", "/", "/")
```

Or, if you want to make sure the names come in the same order as your `myColumns` list:

```
val values = foo.productElementNames.zip(foo.productIterator).toMap.withDefault("")
myColumns.map { case name => s"$name=${values(name)}" }.mkString("/", "/", "/")
```

Before 2.13, you don't have access to names via `Product`, so, if you are sure the list of names is in the same order as class members, you could just use that:

```
myColumns.zip(foo.productIterator)
  .map { case (name, value) => s"$name=$value"}
  .mkString("/", "/", "/")
```

and if you cannot rely on order, then you will need reflection:

```
myColumns
 .map { case name => s"$name=${foo.getClass.getMethod(name).invoke(foo)}" }
 .mkString("/", "/", "/")
```

(this will throw if a column name is invalid)

Note though, that reflection is *really slow*, so, if you need to be running this many times, and want it performant, then you are better off caching the accessors:

```
val methods = classOf[VariablesToMap].getMethods.map { m => m.getName -> m }.toMap
def toString(inst: VariablesToMap, myColumns: Seq[String]) =
   myColumns.map { name => s"$name=${methods.get(name).fold("")(_.invoke(foo)}" }
   .mkString("/", "/", "/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, if you only care about a single class with a reasonable amount of fields I would just keep it simple and do something like:

```scala
def printVariables(fields: String*)(data: VariablesToMap): String =
  fields.view.map {
    case "id" => s"id=${data.id}"
    case "name" => s"name=${data.name}"
    // ...
    case _ => "" // What is the best way to handle a missing field?
  }.mkString("/", "/", "/")
```

---

If you want something more generic that can work for many classes and that scales automatically, I would recommend looking into **Shapeless** to derivate a *typeclass* that either prints the requested fields of a class or generates a `Map[String, String]` for any case class or something similar.